# Illegal return statement

Tags: javascript, return

What is the problem with this code?

Browser says:

"Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal return statement"

I need an answer like:
1
2
3fool
4
5bar
6fool
7
8
9bar...

```
let arr = [];
for (i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
  if (i % 3 === 0) {
    return i + "fool";
  }
  if (i % 5 === 0) {
    return i + "bar";
  }
  console.log(arr.push(i) - 1);
}
```

Comment: you use an return statement outside of a function. what is the purpose of the code?

Comment: what happens with 15?

Comment: 15fool bar, but it is later

Answer (score 1):

If you return anything, you have to put this piece of code inside a function. Here you make return statement inside loop.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is what you want..

```
let arr = [];
for (i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
  if (i % 3 === 0) {
    arr.push( i + "fool");
  }
  else if (i % 5 === 0) {
    arr.push( i + "bar");
  }
  else{
    arr.push(i)
  }
}
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: if you want common 'foobar' then you can follow @Nina Scholz answer before me

Answer (score 0):

You need to push the value to the array. For getting more than one postfix, you could take another variable and collenct the strings.

At the end of the loop push the value.

```js
let array = [];

for (i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
    let value = i;
    if (i % 3 === 0) {
        value += "fool";
    }
    if (i % 5 === 0) {
        value += "bar";
    }
    array.push(value);
}

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

This works perfect. Happy Coding :)

```js
let arr = [];
for (i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
  if (i % 3 === 0 && i % 5 === 0) {
    arr.push(i + "fool bar");
  } else if (i % 3 === 0) {
    arr.push(i + "fool");
  } else if (i % 5 === 0) {
    arr.push(i + "bar");
  } else {
    arr.push(i);
  }
}
```